# Fast way of checking if an element is ranked higher than another

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

I am writing in MATLAB a program that checks whether two elements `A` and `B` were exchanged in ranking positions.

**Example**

Assume the first ranking is:

```
list1 = [1 2 3 4]
```

while the second one is:

```
list2 = [1 2 4 3]
```

I want to check whether `A = 3` and `B = 4` have exchanged relative positions in the rankings, which in this case is true, since in the first ranking `3` comes before `4` and in the second ranking `3` comes after `4`.

**Procedure**

In order to do this, I have written the following MATLAB code:

```
positionA1 = find(list1 == A);
positionB1 = find(list1 == B);
positionA2 = find(list2 == A);
positionB2 = find(list2 == B);
if (positionA1 <= positionB1 && positionA2 >= positionB2) || ...
   (positionA1 >= positionB1 && positionA2 <= positionB2)
      ... do something
end
```

Unfortunately, I need to run this code a lot of times, and the `find` function is really slow (but needed to get the element position in the list).

I was wondering if there is a way of speeding up the procedure. I have also tried to write a MEX file that performs in C the find operation, but it did not help.

Comment: Maybe `find(list1 == A, 1)` (find only the first occurence) speeds things up

Answer (score 1):

If the lists don't change within your loop, then you can determine the positions of the items ahead of time.

Assuming that your items are always integers from 1 to N:

```
[~, positions_1] = sort( list1 );
[~, positions_2] = sort( list2 );
```

This way you won't need to call `find` within the loop, you can just do:

```
positionA1 = positions_1(A);
positionB1 = positions_1(B);
positionA2 = positions_2(A);
positionB2 = positions_2(B);
```

---

If your loop is going over all possible combinations of A and B, then you can also vectorize that

Find the elements that exchanged relative ranking:

```
rank_diff_1 = bsxfun(@minus, positions_1, positions_1');
rank_diff_2 = bsxfun(@minus, positions_2, positions_2');
rel_rank_changed = sign(rank_diff_1) ~= sign(rank_diff_2);
[A_changed, B_changed] = find(rel_rank_changed);
```

Optional: Throw out half of the results, because if (3,4) is in the list, then (4,3) also will be, and maybe you don't want that:

```
mask = (A_changed < B_changed);
A_changed = A_changed(mask);
B_changed = B_changed(mask);
```

Now loop over only those elements that have exchanged relative ranking

```
for ii = 1:length(A_changed)
    A = A_changed(ii);
    B = B_changed(ii);
    % Do something...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find try to compute something like this

Check if there is any exchanged values.

```
if logical(sum(abs(list1-list2)))
    do something
end;
```

For specific values A and B:

```
if (list1(logical((list1-list2)-abs((list1-list2))))==A)&&(list1(logical((list1-list2)+abs((list1-list2))))==B)
    do something
end;
```